# How to know the number of connection pools created in JBOSS application server

Tags: java, jboss

I am using jboss 7.0 for web application. In standalone.xml file, I have defined datasource as ,

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/finacpacds" pool-name="ltmscompanyadmindspool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finacpac?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        mysqldriver
                    </driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>
                        TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                    </transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>
                            10
                        </min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>
                            50
                        </max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>
                            true
                        </prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>
                            false
                        </use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>
                            FailingConnectionOnly
                        </flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            root
                        </user-name>
                        <password>

                        </password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>
                            false
                        </validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>
                            false
                        </background-validation>
                        <useFastFail>
                            false
                        </useFastFail>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                            100
                        </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements/>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Now my question is can i see the number of connection pools created when jboss is running by system.out.print statement. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print out that info to `System.out`. You can read datasource statistics via CLI:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ltmscompanyadmindspool/statistics=pool:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ltmscompanyadmindspool/statistics=jdbc:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
```

You can read more about statistics [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Readstatisticsofactivedatasources]).

On a side note, your datasource configuration is a bit concerning. Why would you have the validations disabled? If you do this then when there is an outage or a restart of the database server JBoss won't be able to validate/refresh the connections without a restart of the JBoss server.